# Module not found: Can't resolve './clock' in '/home/n/MyWork/my-app/src'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, debugging

I am trying to run the project but I am receiving this error.
"Module not found: Can't resolve './clock' in '/home/n/MyWork/my-app/src' "

Project structure is:

```
My-app
--node-modules
--public
--src
-----clock
-----timer
App.js(in src)
```

My App.js has the below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import FilterableProductTable from './FilterableProductTable';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Clock from './clock';
import ProductsContext from './contextobjects';
```

Comment: if App.js and clock.js are in the same folder, the issue might be in the clock.js export statement, which might be missing or might be incorrect (maybe you used `export Clock` instead of `export default Clock`) or in some mispelling of "Clock", either in the declaration or in the export statement.

Comment: Clock is a separate folder which contains other .js files.App.js is outside of CLock folder.

Comment: Then your import statement is wrong; it should be `import Clock from './folder_name/clock'`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understood correctly what your folder structure actually is, it should be:

```
My-app
--node-modules
--public
--src
----clock
------index.js
----timer
------index.js
----App.js
```

in which case the import statement should be `import Clock from './clock/'`

If instead of 'index.js' you named your files 'Clock.js' and 'Timer.js':

```
My-app
--node-modules
--public
--src
----clock
------Clock.js
----timer
------Timer.js
----App.js
```

Then the import statement should be `import Clock from './clock/Clock`